# Android Studio - How do I highlight the selected grid item, and un-highlight all others?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a grid which is made up of lots of items. I want the user to be able to click on an item in the grid; the item should then be highlighted. If a different item is then clicked, the original should be unhighlighted and the new one highlighted.

Each box is a TextView which has a different colour of background. I can't figure out how to highlight, so currently I'm putting an 'X' in the box. My question is how to remove any previously-set X's.

Here's my code so far (patternColour is just an object which has a name and a hex code):

```
coloursGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewColoursGrid);
patternColourAdapter = new PatternColourAdapter(this, R.layout.colour_grid_layout, gridItemsColours);
coloursGrid.setAdapter(patternColourAdapter);
coloursGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Highlight selected colour, and unhighlight all others
        TextView unselected;
        for(int ii=0; ii<parent.getCount(); ii++) {
            unselected = ????; // Don't know what to put here!
            unselected.setText("");
        }
        TextView selected = (TextView) view;
        selected.setText("X");
    }
});
```

No matter what I've tried in place of the question marks, I'm getting errors (either the build fails, or the app crashes at that point).

How do I loop over all the TextViews and unset the text in all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the choiceMode of the GridView to sinngleChoice

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

then set the grid view item layout a state background drawable like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_activated="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you. The choiceMode setting was what I was missing, I think! I've decided to do the colouring-in a different way, using images - when I looked again at what I'm trying to achieve, I think it'll look better. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
 coloursGrid.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

coloursGrid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            coloursGrid.setSelection(arg2)

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

});
```

It may helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your help!